# Why does chrono add a leading plus character when displaying DateTime in far future?

Tags: rust, datetime-format

In chrono's code we can find the following test:

```
assert_eq!(format!("{:?}", NaiveDate::from_ymd(2012, 3, 4)), "2012-03-04");
assert_eq!(format!("{:?}", NaiveDate::from_ymd(0, 3, 4)), "0000-03-04");
assert_eq!(format!("{:?}", NaiveDate::from_ymd(-307, 3, 4)), "-0307-03-04");
assert_eq!(format!("{:?}", NaiveDate::from_ymd(12345, 3, 4)), "+12345-03-04");
```

[See Source here](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/8dd7245f85d230aeb5216f934d3385376f27bbe1/src/naive/date.rs#L2387)

Why is it `+12345-03-04` and not just `12345-03-04` without the leading `+`?

The behavior is similar when using the `DateTime::to_rfc3339` formatting shorthand.

I cannot find any mention of this leading plus in the specifier documentation nor in RFC 3339. Is this correct according to some specification? What's the meaning of the `+` and when is it included?

Comment: Just guess - `+` means that date is outside of the current era (0-9999AD) into future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/src/chrono/naive/date.rs.html#1639-1650

```rust
// ISO 8601 requires the explicit sign for out-of-range years
write!(f, "{:+05}-{:02}-{:02}", year, mdf.month(), mdf.day())
```